# null object reference for Bitmap that is a final property of the object

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm getting *"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference"* (full stack trace below). What I find confusing about this is that the line that is referenced is a **final** property of the class - by the time an instance of the class exists to reference it, it should already be defined:

### Excerpt

```
public class WindView extends View {
...
    private final Bitmap pDirectionArrow = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wind_arrow);
...
    public void setWindOriginDegrees(float mWindOriginDegrees) {
        this.mWindOriginDegrees = mWindOriginDegrees;
        _rotateArrow();
        invalidate();
    }
...
    private Matrix _rotateArrow() {
        pMatrix.setRotate((180+mWindOriginDegrees)%360, pDirectionArrow.getWidth() / 2, pDirectionArrow.getHeight() / 2);
        return pMatrix;
    }
```

### Call

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
...
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
...
            WindView windGraphic = new WindView(getActivity());
            windGraphic.setWindSpeed((int) windSpeedStr);
            windGraphic.setWindOriginDegrees(windDirStr);
            windGraphic.setForegroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sunshine_light_blue));
            windGraphic.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sunshine_dark_blue));
            parent.addView(windGraphic, parent.indexOfChild(mWindView) + 1);
```

#### Full Class

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by RobertoTomás on 0023, 23/3/2016.
 */
public class WindView extends View {
    private static final float GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DIP = 16.0f;

    private final Bitmap pDirectionArrow = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wind_arrow);
    private final Bitmap pCompassRing = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wind_compass_ring);
    private final Paint pSpeedText = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    private final Matrix pMatrix = new Matrix();

    private Float pDensity;
    private Rect pSpeedTextBoundingRectangle;

    private int mForegroundColor;

    private int mBackgroundColor;
    private int mWindSpeed;
    private float mWindOriginDegrees;

    public float getWindOriginDegrees() {
        return mWindOriginDegrees;
    }

    public void setWindOriginDegrees(float mWindOriginDegrees) {
        this.mWindOriginDegrees = mWindOriginDegrees;
        _rotateArrow();
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getForegroundColor() {
        return mForegroundColor;
    }

    public void setForegroundColor(int foregroundColor) {
        this.mForegroundColor = foregroundColor;
        _changeForegroundColor();
        invalidate();
    }

    private void _changeForegroundColor(){
        int [] allpixels = new int [pDirectionArrow.getHeight()* pDirectionArrow.getWidth()];

        pDirectionArrow.getPixels(allpixels, 0, pDirectionArrow.getWidth(), 0, 0, pDirectionArrow.getWidth(), pDirectionArrow.getHeight());

        for(int i = 0; i < allpixels.length; i++)
        {
            if(allpixels[i] == Color.BLACK)
            {
                allpixels[i] = mForegroundColor;
            }
        }

        pDirectionArrow.setPixels(allpixels, 0, pDirectionArrow.getWidth(), 0, 0, pDirectionArrow.getWidth(), pDirectionArrow.getHeight());
    }

    public int getBackgroundColor() {
        return mBackgroundColor;
    }

    public void setBackgroundColor(int backgroundColor) {
        this.mBackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        _changeBackgroundColor();
        invalidate();
    }

    private void _changeBackgroundColor(){
        int [] allpixels = new int [pCompassRing.getHeight()* pCompassRing.getWidth()];

        pCompassRing.getPixels(allpixels, 0, pCompassRing.getWidth(), 0, 0, pCompassRing.getWidth(), pCompassRing.getHeight());

        for(int i = 0; i < allpixels.length; i++)
        {
            if(allpixels[i] == Color.BLACK)
            {
                allpixels[i] = mBackgroundColor;
            }
        }

        pCompassRing.setPixels(allpixels, 0, pCompassRing.getWidth(), 0, 0, pCompassRing.getWidth(), pCompassRing.getHeight());
    }

    public int getWindSpeed() {
        return mWindSpeed;
    }

    public void setWindSpeed(int wind_speed) {
        this.mWindSpeed = wind_speed;
        invalidate();
    }

    public String getWindSpeedText (){
        return Integer.toString(mWindSpeed);
    }

    /** Constructors **/
    public WindView(Context c){
        super(c);
        objectHandler();
    }
    public WindView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);
        objectHandler();
    }
    public WindView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs, int DefaultStyle) {
        super(c, attrs, DefaultStyle);
        objectHandler();
    }

    public void objectHandler(){
        this.mForegroundColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark_material_light);
        this.mBackgroundColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_material_dark);
        this.mWindSpeed = 0;
        this.mWindOriginDegrees = 0;

        this.pDensity = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        this.pSpeedText.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        this.pSpeedText.setColor(mForegroundColor);
        this.pSpeedText.setAntiAlias(true);
        int textSize = (int) (GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DIP * pDensity + 0.5f);
        textSize *= pDensity;
        this.pSpeedText.setTextSize(textSize);
        this.pSpeedText.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);

        Typeface typeface = Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF,Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
        this.pSpeedText.setTypeface(typeface);
        this.pSpeedTextBoundingRectangle = new Rect();
    }

    private Matrix _rotateArrow() {
        pMatrix.setRotate((180+mWindOriginDegrees)%360, pDirectionArrow.getWidth() / 2, pDirectionArrow.getHeight() / 2);
        return pMatrix;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.translate(18 * pDensity, 18 * pDensity);

        canvas.drawBitmap(pCompassRing, 0, 0, null);

        String txt = pSpeedText + " km/h";
        pSpeedText.getTextBounds(
                txt, // text
                0, // start
                txt.length(), // end
                pSpeedTextBoundingRectangle // bounds
        );
        canvas.drawText(
                txt, // Text to draw
                canvas.getWidth() / 2, // x
                canvas.getHeight() / 2 + Math.abs(pSpeedTextBoundingRectangle.height()) / 2, // y
                pSpeedText // Paint
        );

        canvas.drawBitmap(pDirectionArrow, _rotateArrow(), null);

    }
}
```

#### Stack trace

```
03-23 18:37:47.870 4152-4152/com.example.android.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.android.sunshine.app, PID: 4152
                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.example.android.sunshine.app.WindView._rotateArrow(WindView.java:147)
                                                                                    at com.example.android.sunshine.app.WindView.setWindOriginDegrees(WindView.java:42)
                                                                                    at com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailFragment.onLoadFinished(DetailFragment.java:227)
                                                                                    at com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailFragment.onLoadFinished(DetailFragment.java:44)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:427)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:395)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:104)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:73)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:35)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:223)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:61)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.finish(ModernAsyncTask.java:461)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.access$500(ModernAsyncTask.java:47)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(ModernAsyncTask.java:474)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: final doesn't mean that a field must not be null. It just tells you that it will be initialized exactly once. So, when you initialize it to null, well; then it is null and stays null. So could it be that the methods to "decode" return null? Maybe because the resource the are looking for is empty, null, corrupted, ... ?!

Comment: You're saying that `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wind_arrow);` is returning null instead of a Bitmap? But it was a standard vector resource that imported just fine after I changed gradle to version 1.4

Comment: I am merely following advise of good old Sherlock Holmes: "When you have excluded the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth." No, seriously; I was only suggesting to check the result of that call to be sure to understand what is going on ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it turns out that the problem was that `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wind_arrow);` assumes the resource will become a `BitmapDrawable` not a `VectorDrawable`. In my opinion, this is on the verge of being a bug in android. <s>I am going to report it.</s> I [reported it](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204950&thanks=204950&ts=1458829079).

A solution is to assign it in the constuctor like:

```
private Bitmap _getBitmap(int drawableId, int color) {
    Drawable vectorDrawable;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        vectorDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(drawableId,null);
    }else {
        vectorDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(drawableId);
    }

    // Wrap the drawable so that future tinting calls work
    // on pre-v21 devices. Always use the returned drawable.
    Drawable wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(vectorDrawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable.mutute(), getResources().getColor(color));

    int h = vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    int w = vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    //Setting a pixel default if intrinsic height or width is not found , eg a shape drawable
    h=h>0?h:96;
    w=w>0?w:96;

    wrapDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
    wrapDrawable.draw(canvas);
    return bm;
}
```

right now I am actually still having issues with the color (both `mutate` and `wrap` are highlighting in red and offer no resolution with Alt+enter), but that was just bolted on after I checked that the basic solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change declaration of your Bitmap to:

```
private Bitmap pDirectionArrow;
```

Then call get resources on your bitmap inside the constructor of the view like this:

```
pDirectionArrow = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.wind_arrow);
```

getResources needs the context of the app.

Comment: that was what I was thinking yesterday when I was writing it (before even testing it), but the code I am using here is from another solution, I think it should work. Still, I tried your solution and would have happily been wrong .. but alas, I get the same problem.